# Unable to locate /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/lib/javaws.jar in /usr/share/java

Tags: 11.04, java

Looks like 11.04 missing javaws.jar.
Not sure if it is intentional.

```
/usr/share/java$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.1) (6b22-1.10.1-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try and install Sun (now Oracle) Java version. You can find in that repository ppa:ferramroberto/java. You can add these repositry using that command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
```

And install:

```
sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

I don't remeber if it is necessery but maybe you have to use `update-java-alternatives` command to change the default Java engine.